# making sure one task completes before another starts in java

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Can anyone show me a way to force one task in java to complete before the next task is allows to start?  Specifically, I want to edit the code below so that the first marked two lines of code are completely finished before the next marked two lines are called.

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
    throws ServletException, IOException {
      String idString = req.getParameter("id");
      Long id = new Long(idString);
//complete the actions specified on next two lines
      School school = new SchoolDAO().findSchool(id);
      req.setAttribute("school", school);
//before even starting the actions specified on the next two lines
      List<CourseSummary> coursesummaries = new CourseSummaryDAO().findAllcsum(id);
      req.setAttribute("coursesummaries", coursesummaries);

      jsp.forward(req, resp);
}
```

---

### EDIT:

To better understand Fernando's suggestion, I am including some relevant parts of SchoolDAO as follows:

```
public class SchoolDAO extends DataAccessObject{
    public School findSchool(Long id) {
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = getConnection();
            String sql = "select * from schoolprog where id=?";
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setLong(1, id.longValue());
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if (!rs.next()) {return null;}
            return readSchool(rs);
         }
         catch (SQLException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);}
         finally {close(rs, statement, connection);}
      }
      private School readSchool(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
          Long id = new Long(rs.getLong("id"));
          String spname = rs.getString("spname");
          String spurl = rs.getString("spurl");
          School school = new School();
          school.setId(id);
          school.setName(spname);
          school.setUrl(spurl);
          return school;
      }
}
```

Similarly, CourseSummaryDAO contains:

```
public class CourseSummaryDAO extends DataAccessObject{
    public List<CourseSummary> findAllcsum(Long sid) {
        LinkedList<CourseSummary> coursesummaries = new LinkedList<CourseSummary>();
        ResultSet rs = null;
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            connection = getConnection(); //this is the line throwing null pointer error
      String sql = "select * from coursetotals where spid=?";
            statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            statement.setLong(1, sid);
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
      //for every row, call read method to extract column 
            //values and place them in a coursesummary instance
            while (rs.next()) {
                CourseSummary coursesummary = readcsum("findAll", rs);
                coursesummaries.add(coursesummary);
            }
            return coursesummaries;
         }
         catch (SQLException e) {throw new RuntimeException(e);} 
         finally {close(rs, statement, connection);}
     }
```

The line where the program is breaking is:

```
connection = getConnection(); //
```

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing that makes you think those lines _aren't_ completing first? They must be run before execution reaches the following lines...

Comment: @MattR think maybe he means the result of calling those lines is complete, not that the lines are executed.

Comment: You can use a CountdownLatch object. See this question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811681/java-threads-waiting-value

Comment: @MattR Deep in the code, there is a problem with a second database connection not being able to open up because a first connection has not closed.  However, the connections are both explicitly closed in the code.  I think it is just a question of being a few milliseconds too early, and I was hoping there was something at the level listed in this posting that would enable the program to wait until the first tasks completely returned before starting the second tasks.  I am investigating the deeper problem in other ways separately.

Comment: @CodeMed we'd need more information about your classes to help you I think. The code at this level doesn't offer a way to block, or be notified of async operation completion.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison, can you please explain how those 2 lines can be *asynchronous* ? Isn't *java code* inside a function *synchronous* ?

Comment: @RaviTrivedi they could kick off a task on another thread for some processing is what I mean. Yes, code inside a function is synchronous, but that code could be doing anything. Including creating threads or submitting tasks for a thread to process.

Comment: @WilliamMorrison, well, isn't that a totally diff Question ? :)

Comment: No. I think this is what he's asking for. A way to ensure some async task (closing the database) is completed before the next lines are executed, right?

Comment: Who knew a findSchool(id) method could be so complex? ;-)

Comment: @MattR yeah, it actually performs a parallel search using 8 cores and 10GB RAM on 10 billion entries... except each search is linear... :)

Comment: This task is just a search on the db? what do you mean by 'each search'?

Comment: @Fernando I just added the rest of what I think is the relevant code.

Comment: I guess your getConnection() is the problem now.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two tasks that should be performed serially (i.e. one finishes before the next one starts) then the best answer is to perform them synchronously.  For instance, suppose that `task1()` and `task2()` are the tasks:

```
// Wrong way:
Runnable r1 = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        task1();
    }};
Runnable r2 = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        // Wait for r1 to finish task1 ... somehow
        task2();
    }};

// Right way:
Runnable r = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {
        task1();
        task2();
    }};
```

And in your case, it *looks like* the `doGet` call can only return when it gets the result of both tasks.  So that suggests that you shouldn't be using threads at all in this case.  Just call `task1()` and `task2()` in sequence ... on the request thread.

---

**EDIT**

Looking at the `doGet` method and the two classes that you added subsequently, it *looks* like the processing is *already* sequential / serial.  That is, the first "task" ends before the second "task" starts.

The problem with `getConnection()` throwing `NullPointerException` is (most likely) nothing to do with asynchrony.  However I can't be sure of that without seeing the code of `getConnection()` and the *complete* stacktrace.

Comment: What if `task1()` is a asynchronous task and you still want `task2()` to start only after `task1()` is completely done with its execution?

Comment: Ask a new question ... providing code that illustrates what you mean by an asynchronous task.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. Here's the question --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125689/how-to-make-sure-a-task-starts-its-execution-only-after-a-previous-asynchronous

Answer (score 1):

In Java, everything is normally executed *in order*, meaning that a given line of code will completely finish executing before the next line will start to do anything. The exception to this rule is when threads come into play. Threads allow multiple blocks of code to execute simultaneously. Because you aren't using any threads in your program (you'd know if you were, don't worry), it's guaranteed that the first two lines of code will complete before the next two begin to be executed.

So, your problem doesn't seem to be that your code is running "out of order". It's likely that your error is somewhere within the `getConnection()` method if that's what's throwing the NPE.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example (see [Java Threads waiting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7811681/java-threads-waiting-value) for details)

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

class MyTask implements Runnable
{

    CountDownLatch signal;

    public MyTask(CountDownLatch signal)
    {
        this.signal = signal;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("starting task");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++)
            Math.random();

        //call when the task is done
        signal.countDown();
    }
}


public class Program
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int workers = 1;
        CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(workers);

        new Thread(new MyTask(signal)).start();

         try {
                // Waits for all the works to finish ( only 1 in this case)
                signal.await();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println("task is done");
        }

}
```

This is just a suggestion, maybe there's a better design:

```
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

public class SchoolDAO extends DataAccessObject implements Runnable {

    Long id;
    CountDownLatch signal;
    School searchResult;

    public SchoolDAO(Long id, CountDownLatch signal)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.signal = signal;
    }

    public void run()
    {
       searchResult = findSchool(id);
       signal.countDown();
    }

    // the other methods didn't change
}
```

Now you can call it inside doGet():

```
CountDownLatch signal = new CountDownLatch(1);
SchoolDAO dao = new SchoolDAO(id, signal);

new Thread(dao).start();
try {        
      signal.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
 School result = dao.searchResult;
```

Comment: I seem to have reached a dead end on another java problem.  Do you have a little time to look at it and help me solve it?  I posted it in another question at this link:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307310/beancreationexception-after-adding-two-variables