# How to make sure a task starts its execution only after a previous asynchronous task has completed its execution?

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have two tasks - `task1()` and `task2()`. `task1()` fetches a value from the internet and adds it with a `int` variable named `num`. Variable `num` is accessible to both `task1()` and `task2()`. `task2()` is just supposed to print the value of variable `num`.

But the problem here is that before the value is fetched from the internet ,the `num` variable gets printed.

```
int num = 0;
public static void main(String[] args)
{
     task1();
     task2();
}

public static void task1()
{
    int fetchedValue;
    rootRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            fetchedValue = Integer.parseInt(snapshot.getValue().toString());
            num = num + fetchedValue ;
        }

        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError arg0) {
            System.out.println("cancelled");
        }
    });
    num = num + fetchedValue;

}

public static void task2()
{
    System.out.println("Updated number : "+num);
}
```

Comment: Call task2() from onPostExecute() of task1().

Comment: I am using `Firebase` not async task.

Comment: Use [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) to post an event at the end of the first task, and upon receiving that event, fire up the 2nd task.

Comment: As you have written it, `task1` is synchronous.  Please show >>in code<< what you mean by an asynchronous task.

Comment: Call `task2` at the end of `onDataChange()` method.

Comment: @PrerakSola : I may not always want to print the value of `num` when I fetch value from internet. I may want to perform different tasks with the fetchedValue other than printing it. So I want to keep my `task1()` and `task2()` independent of each other.

Comment: If your `task2`'s operations are dependent on `task1` you'll have to link them somehow. Maybe you can pass a flag when calling `task2` from `task1` so that the dependent functionalities are executed at that time. And the other time all other tasks are executed.

Comment: Is there  some other better way than using a flag. Can I somehow pause the execution of task2 until task1 is done with its execution?

Comment: If you pause `task2` for `task1` , what will you do when you want to call `task2` not from `task1`? You will need to differentiate between the calls in some way. Or separate the dependent and independent functionalities of `task2`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a boolean to determine if the value has been fetched.

This boolean is accessible from both tasks. task1 changes boolean to `true` if it has completed fetching. task2 checks in a loop whether fetching has finished and prints `num` if `num` has been fetched.

Comment: This sounds good but don't know if this is the ideal solution as what if the value never arrives from the internet or arrives very late. Wouldn't this then loop forever or for a very long time.

Comment: In this case you could use an int or char to indicate different results of fetching.